# Reading from a File from the Website and Changing its Contents using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm using a JavaScript file to read the contents of a text file, in this case, a number, and raising it by 1. The script itself works when I run it in node. I'm trying to bind the script to a button in HTML (trigger the script on click), but when I call the js function in the onClick part of the button tag, nothing happens. The number in the file doesn't change. I know the button works because if I bind another js file to it, which sends an alert, it triggers correctly.

The script is in a different folder from the HTML file it's linked to.
I tried changing the path in the script to act as if it were working from where the HTML is, thinking maybe it's confused as to where the file is.

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Bottle Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/alertcheck.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/counter.js"></script>
</head>

 <body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="section">
            This is the about section with a
            counter button which adds 1 to the file when clicked.

            <br><br>
            <input type='button' id='button' class="button" 
            value='Button' onclick='AddOne()'>
            <br><br>

            <b>Numbercount in file: <span id="readnumber"></span></b>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript, which works on its own if I run it outside the function, but does not react when linked with the button:

```
function AddOne(){
  var fs = require('fs');

  var readnumber = fs.readFileSync("../../data/clickcount.txt", "utf-8");
  var readnum = "Count identified:"
  console.log(readnum, readnumber);

  var newnumber = parseInt(readnumber)+1
  fs.writeFileSync("../../data/clickcount.txt", newnumber);
  var writenum = "Count changed to:"
  console.log(writenum, newnumber);
};
```

When clicking the button, nothing changes, no errors (I suppose because there's no console) and the number in the file does not change. But when I run a script in the same directory as the number counter, it works with no problem. Any ideas why?

Also, bonus points for someone who can explain how to show the number from the text file in HTML, JavaScript's file system doesn't seem to react at all in the script tag in the HTML file.

Comment: Javascript in a browser and in Node.js run very differently.  You can't do what you're trying to do with Javascript running in a browser.  You can get the file contents (if the file is accessible from a Url), but not modify it and save it.

Comment: The code you are using to read and write the file is server-side, while your HTML page is client-side. You cannot run server-side code from the client; you'd need to have the client send a request to the server (using AJAX, usually) and then the server can react to that request by doing what you want, and then respond with the result. The client can then handle the response as needed.

Comment: I see, it seems I have much to learn :/